# shell script within crontab

Tags: shell, cron

I can run the following shell script from command prompt as expected:

```
/bin/sh -xv /home/shantanu/backup_transfer.sh
```

But when I set it in a cron, it does not execute correctly. 
There are 2 commands. ssh -t abc@10.10.10.100 "sudo ls" and sudo rsync -avze to another server.

Why would a shell script fail in a cron when it runs successfully at command prompt?

```
$ which sh
/bin/sh
```

Am I using the correct environment?

Update:

```
Error for the first ssh -t command:
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

Error for the second sudo rsync command: 
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

No error while running the script at command prompt.

Comment: Does these commands require `sudo`? Did you configure with passwordless?

Comment: Yes. it works as expected from command prompt. it is passwordless copy to remote server.

Comment: 1. Always use the absolute path when doing something in cron. 2. Redirect both of error and output to a log file to see what happens `command >> /tmp/log 2>&1`

Comment: question updated with error out info.

Comment: Use double `-t` or edit your `/etc/sudoers` file with something like this `Defaults:abc !requiretty`. Why didn't you [search](http://www.google.com.vn/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=vi&source=hp&q=%22sudo:+sorry%2C+you+must+have+a+tty+to+run+sudo%22+site%3Aserverfault.com&pbx=1&oq=%22sudo:+sorry%2C+you+must+have+a+tty+to+run+sudo%22+site%3Aserverfault.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=62786l64323l13l64498l11l6l0l0l0l1l130l633l3.3l6l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=1e5bb8b655785418&biw=1280&bih=665) the above error in this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correct the sudo tty error you need to modify the /etc/sudoers file on the host that you are issuing the sudo command on.

```
#Here is an example of how to turn off the requirement of a tty for a user called "USERNAME"
Defaults:USERNAME !requiretty
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating /etc/sudoers and inserting !requiretty is the best option. However, in certain cases you might not have access on the remote system to enable/disable requiretty in /etc/sudoers.

In these situations you can use a double tt as a workaround. A double tt even works in cron.

`ssh -tt user@remoteserver /some/dir/remotecommand`